# JMeter test not running

Tags: java, jmeter

```
5/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/03/25 09:36:45 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

I am trying to load test my application with JMeter but it doesnt seem as though it is running my test correctly, the log file for the application shows no signs of incoming messages but my test log output from JMeter shows the above - it appears as though the test is running from this - can anyone shed some clarity on what might be going wrong or what I might have not done?

Comment: My guess is your webserver/ip path within your (I am assuming) HTTP Request Default/sample element has a problem?  .If you copy the webserver path to your browser does your application open?  Make sure the path is set to "/"  under the sampler as well.

Comment: its my jar that makes a zero mq call to my java middleware application on localhost requester.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

Comment: Use a listener (the table as suggested below), it won't fix your problem but it will indicate on the success/failures on each thread.  Try removing tcp:// if that's included in the servername/ip box (the http element handles the protocol)...I imagine the TCP Sampler is the same (What sampler are you using? ( I imagine the TCP Sampler? ))

Comment: hi thanks for the advice  - yes a tcp sampler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a 'View results in a table' Listener to your Thread Group. This will show you each request and the result - eg if it's HTTP you will get URL, status code etc.

Have a look at the doco [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table)

Comment: Good idea, this shows me that the calls are working just not displaying in the tree view.  Any ideas on why?

Comment: Ok I am a goon, I had the Error checkbox selected, which is why I did not see anything in the tree view.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check below things before hitting the run button:

1. Make Sure the "Thread Group" is Enabled (Not sure but for me it was disabled when I open my .JMX file from recent files), If you have Login parameter added then make sure it is enabled as well.
2. Go to the location where you kept the .CSV file and double check the path in Jmeter as well. Because without the csv data it will stop the Thread at 1-1. (Above Error)
3. Make Sure the Results (Listeners) are merged with the Thread and are Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any regular expression extractors or CSV Data set config files empty? No data or capturing anything? If so, please toggle them off (Ctrl+T) or Cmmnd+T - OSX, Linux. Should fix that

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the same error
screenshot of error log:
[image: screenshot of error log]

However, removed the HTTP part from the IP address and it worked fine.
screenshot of the http request page:
[image: screenshot of the http request page]

Answer (score 0):

i tried to put the full link in the path field and it worked successfully

Comment: Your answer doesn't have any information that you tried to put